# Gramex is not opening

Tags: gramex

When I install Gramex and try to run it, I get this error message.

[image: Gramex error message]

```
gramex: The term 'gramex' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that Gramex is not on your PATH. That can happen if:

1. Anaconda itself is not on your PATH. Please reboot and run "conda" and see if it's in your PATH. If not, please re-install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and add it to your PATH when you install.
2. Gramex was not installed properly. Please [re-install Gramex](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/install/#conda-install) and see if there were any errors.

If this does not resolve it, please reply, and we can explore.